# Atomically increment two integers with CAS

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, compare-and-swap

Apparently, it is possible to atomically increment two integers with compare-and-swap instructions. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1obZeHnAwz4&t=1251) claims that such an algorithm exists but it does not detail what it looks like.

[image]

How can this be done?

(Note, that the obvious solution of incrementing the integers one after the other is not atomic. Also, stuffing multiple integers into one machine word does not count because it would restrict the possible range.)

Comment: "stuffing multiple integers into one machine word does not count "  I would think the mention of 128-bit CAS and two 64 bit integers is suggesting exactly that, though?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul that's a different algorithm. The slide claims there is an algorithm with one-word CAS and three words involved. I guess the 3rd word is a "helper word". Maybe some kind of scratch space.

Comment: Ah, OK, didn't see that.

Comment: You really have to be careful what you are comparing. CAS may not be the best instruction for an architecture like the x86 since it has a native `atomic_fetch_add`. Except for overflow, adding `1<<64 + 1` (the bit pattern), would then do the increment of the two words.

Comment: @JensGustedt here, when I say word I mean one 64 bit CAS unit. That's how I understand the slide and audio. And atomic_fetch_add only increments one such word.

Comment: An atomic increment could be a user-space lock, not necessarily a single CAS instruction. The helper could be as simple as a spin lock or a stamped lock. The slides are vague to assume the clever approach is, in fact, clever.

Comment: @boot4life, these architectures allow atomic operations on different word sizes. E.g some common processor variants allow a CAS for 8, 16, 32, 64 and 128 bit, so it makes not much sense of talking about *the* word size. There may well be some in the future that allow for 128 add.  All that I am saying is that such general claims make not much sense. All of this depends a lot of the (sub-) architecture, compiler,  and the choice of the particular atomic instruction.

Comment: @BenManes the whole talk is about lock and wait-free algorithms. Locking is not "clever", either :) In fact he mentions that as the next bullet.

Comment: @JensGustedt it's not DCAS because that's covered in the bullet before. Not sure why it would depend on architecture and compiler. It seems pretty clear that we are talking about 3 64 bit integers and all you have is normal instructions plus a 64 bit CAS. You can of course also play tricks on reading. Reads can read multiple integers and somehow combine them.

Comment: @boot4life Using a helper field means he's probably using a spin lock, so not overly clever. And locking can be clever and more efficient than lock-free algorithms, so its finding the right trick to use in a given situation. You might want to email the speaker and ask for the details.

Comment: I would have thought that the obvious solution is to use x, y and t such that the first number is x+t and the second number is y+t. That maked incrementing either or both a single CAS but leaves open the question of how to atomically _read_ the two numbers.

Comment: @BenManes I don't think a spinlock qualifies as "really clever" especially considering that it is called out as the 3rd alternative. He surely will not mention spinlocks twice as two identical alternatives. If nobody comes up with a solution I'll probably indeed email him and post the solution.

Comment: @rici could explain more (probably in an answer), I don't understand... How do you find `t` atomically and how to you create `x+t` and `y+t` with a single CAS?

Comment: @laeme: you can't create all three variables atomically with a single CAS. The question doesn't have to do with initialization, only with incrementing. And you can modify any one of the variables atomically; if you atomically increment `t`, you will effectively atomically increment both `x+t` and `y+t`. Also, you cannot discover the three values with a single CAS, but you couldn't discover two values (`x` and `y`) with a single CAS either and without that "atomically incrementing" is meaningless. So I'm assuming that is a separate requirement, too.

Comment: I've seen this done before, but I don't remember all of the details. I *think* It involved having the two 64-bit integers and a 64-bit sequence number in an array. `array[0] = X, array[1] = sequence, array[2] = Y'. The 128-bit CAS can then  manipulate either `[X, sequence]` or `[sequence, Y]` (assuming there are no conflicting alignment restrictions on the 128-bit CAS). It's 3:17am here, I'll think about & research this more after a bit of sleep.

Comment: Is your question specifically about how to do so using a 3rd integer? This isn't very clear.

Comment: I believe (but am not sure) that he may be referring to the "Multi-word compare-&-swap (MCAS)" algorithm described in Section 3.2 of Kier Fraser's ["Practical lock-freedom"](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-579.pdf) paper.

Comment: Another paper that might shed some light on this is an earlier one by Fraser along with Timothy Harris and Ian Pratt: [A Practical Multi-Word Compare-and-Swap Operation](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/netos/papers/2002-casn.pdf)

Comment: Meanwhile I corresponded with the speaker. I do not understand the algorithm to an extent that I could post an answer. But the 3rd integer (called v) is used as a "versioned lock". When writing, v is reset to zero. When the write is complete set v to v+1. The answer by gby seems to be in that spirit but different.

Comment: @rici I suspect your comment is the one that was referred to in the slide and it's certainly much better than the existing answers, so I'd advocate your turning it into an answer.  One nit:  to increment x and y atomically, you decrement t rather than incrementing it.

Answer (score 4):

Make me think of a sequence lock. Not very accurate (putting this from memory) but  something along the lines of:

let x,y and s be 64 bit integers.

To increment:

`atomic s++` (I mean atomic increment using 64 bit CAS op)

```
memory barrier
atomic x++
atomic y++
atomic s++
memory barrier
```

To read:

```
do {
    S1 = load s
    X = load x
    Y = load y
    memory barrier
    S2 = load s
} while (S1 != S2)
```

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock

Comment: This seems very flawed to me. What prevents a reader from believing he has a good read after only `x` has been incremented?

Comment: @Michael So the provided implementation doesn't quite work for a seq lock. A correct implementation would increase `s` before **and** after the write. Additionally when reading, you have to check that `s` is not an odd number (aka. that there are no ongoing writes) and you also have to ensure to hold a mutex while doing the write (can spin on odd values of `s`). Note that all it allows is for multiple concurrent readers while there are no ongoing writers. That being said, I can't think of any other solution to the given problem so this is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Just remembered that I had a toy implementation lying around so, for the curious: https://github.com/RAttab/lockless/blob/master/src/seq_lock.h

Comment: @ZeBlob: I haven't looked at you implementation, but from your description of an improvement that increment `s` before the updates to `x` & `y` it seems there would still be a problem when there are multiple concurrent writers.

Comment: @Michael Which is why multiple concurrent writers are not allowed. So, when you want to write, you either you grab a mutex or spin if `s` has an odd value.

Comment: @ZeBlob: spinning on an odd `s` might be a step in the right direction; the initial increment of `s` would need to be using an atomic  compare & exchange, which is fine. I'm not yet convinced that would solve all problems - I (or someone smarter than me) would have to consider it a bit more.  Also: this makes `s` more or less a mutex or spin-lock, so maybe this falls more under the "Do it under a spinlock or use atomic exchange and busy-wait" bullet point rather than the "There is a really clever algorithm with CAS and a 3rd integer" bullet point being asked about?

Comment: @MichaelBurr The best way to view a sequence lock is as a read-write lock where writes have precedence over reads (ie. a write doesn't have to wait after ongoing reads). So yes, I wouldn't call this a lock-free approach since there's no guarantee that at least one thread is making progress (eg. if the write thread is pre-empted then everyone is spinning and no progress is made). Note that, unless it relies on a weird architecture trick (see answer below), then I'm starting to think that there's no answer to this question. I stopped just short of building a proof that it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

If sse2 is available, you can use *paddq* to add 2 64 bit integers to two other 64 bit integers in one instruction.

```
#include "emmintrin.h"
//initialize your values somewhere:
//const __m128i ones = _mm_set1_epi64x(1);
//volatile register __m128i vars = 
//    _mm_set_epi64x(24,7);
static inline __m128i inc_both(__m128i vars, __m128i ones){
  return _mm_add_epi64(vars,ones);
}
```

This should compile to

```
    paddq  %xmm0, %xmm1
```

Since it is static inline, it may use other xmm registers though.  If there is significant register pressure the ones operands may become *ones(℅rip)*

Note: this can be used for adding values other than 1 and there are similar operations for most other math, bitwise and compare instructions, should you need them.

So you can use the lock prefix and make it into an inline asm macro

```
#define inc64x2(vars) asm volatile( \
    "paddq %0, %1\n":"+x"(vars):"x"(ones) \
  );
```

The arm neon equivalent is something like: vaddq_s64(...), but there is a great article about arm/x86 equivalents [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/12/12/from-arm-neon-to-intel-mmxsse-automatic-porting-solution-tips-and-tricks).

Comment: Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2 (2A, 2B & 2C): Instruction Set Reference, A-Z: `LOCK The LOCK prefix can be prepended only to the following instructions and only to those forms of the instructions where the destination operand is a memory operand: ADD, ADC, AND, BTC, BTR, BTS, CMPXCHG, CMPXCH8B, CMPXCHG16B, DEC, INC, NEG, NOT, OR, SBB, SUB, XOR, XADD, and XCHG. [...] An undefined opcode exception will also be generated if the LOCK prefix is used with any instruction not in the above list.`.

Comment: @EOF thanks, my original macro used cmpexchg16b as described in the OP's link, I removed it from the new version now.

Comment: Now nothing about your answer is atomic. Also, `paddq` cannot have memory as the destination.

Comment: Well, any use of an instruction atomically updating to locations is cheating and it makes the question trivial.

Comment: I don't care about "cheating". This doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution I've tested.  Contained herein is a soup to nuts proof of concept program.

The algorithm is a "use CAS thread id gate" as the 3rd integer.  I watched the video talk twice, and I believe this qualifies.  It may not be *the* algorithm that the presenter was thinking of, but it does work.

The X and Y values can be anywhere in memory and the program places them far enough away from each other that they are on different cache lines.  It doesn't really matter.

---

**A quick description of the algorithm:**

Each thread has a `unique id number` or `tid` (non-zero), taken from one's favorite source: `pthead_t`, `getpid`, `gettid`, `make one up by whatever means you want`.  In the program, it just assigns them sequentially starting from 1.

Each thread will call the increment function with this number.

The increment function will spin on a global `gate` variable using CAS with an old value of 0 and a new value of `tid`.

When the CAS succeeds, the thread now "owns" things.  In other words, if the `gate` is zero, it's up for grabs.  A non-zero value is the `tid` of the owner and the `gate` is locked.

Now, the owner is free to increment the `X` and `Y` values with simple `x += 1` and `y += 1`.

After that, the increment function releases by doing a store of 0 into the `gate`.

---

Here is the diagnostic/proof-of-concept program with everything.  The algorithm *itself* has no restrictions, but I coded it for my machine.

Some caveats:

- It assumes `gcc`/`clang`
- It assumes a 64 bit `x86_64` arch.
- This was coded using nothing but inline asm and needs *no* [nor uses any] compiler `atomic` support for clarity, simplicity, and transparency.
- This was built under linux, but should work on any "reasonable" x86 machine/OS (e.g. BSD, OSX should be fine, cygwin probably, and mingw maybe)
- Other arches are fine if they support CAS, I just didn't code for them (e.g. `arm` might work if you code the CAS with `ldex/stex` pairs)
- There are enough abstract primitives that this would/should be easy.
- No attempt at Windows compatibility [if you want it, do your own port but send me no tears--or comments :-)].
- The makefile and program have been defaulted to best values
- Some x86 CPUs may need to use different defaults (e.g. need fence instructions).  See the makefile.

Anyway, here it is:

```
// caslock -- prove cas lock algorithm

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define systls              __thread

// repeat the madness only once
#ifdef __clang__
#define inline_common       inline
#else
#define inline_common       static inline
#endif
#define inline_always       inline_common __attribute__((__always_inline__))
#define inline_never        __attribute__((__noinline__))

// WARNING: inline CAS fails for gcc but works for clang!
#if _USE_CASINLINE_
#define inline_cas          inline_always
#else
#define inline_cas          inline_never
#endif

typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

#ifndef LOOPMAX
#define LOOPMAX             1000000
#endif

#ifndef TIDMAX
#define TIDMAX              20
#endif

#if _USE_VPTR_
typedef volatile u32 *xptr32_p;
typedef volatile u64 *xptr64_p;
#else
typedef u32 *xptr32_p;
typedef u64 *xptr64_p;
#endif

#if _USE_TID64_
typedef u64 tid_t;
#define tidload(_xptr)                  loadu64(_xptr)
#define tidcas(_xptr,_oval,_nval)       casu64(_xptr,_oval,_nval)
#define tidstore(_xptr,_nval)           storeu64(_xptr,_nval)
#else
typedef u32 tid_t;
#define tidload(_xptr)                  loadu32(_xptr)
#define tidcas(_xptr,_oval,_nval)       casu32(_xptr,_oval,_nval)
#define tidstore(_xptr,_nval)           storeu32(_xptr,_nval)
#endif
tid_t tidgate;                          // gate control
tid_t readycnt;                         // number of threads ready
tid_t donecnt;                          // number of threads complete

// ensure that the variables are nowhere near each other
u64 ary[100];
#define kickoff     ary[32]             // sync to fire threads
#define xval        ary[31]             // the X value
#define yval        ary[87]             // the Y value

int inctype;                            // increment algorithm to use
tid_t tidmax;                           // maximum number of tasks
u64 loopmax;                            // loop maximum for each task

// task control
struct tsk {
    tid_t tsk_tid;                      // task id
    u32 tsk_casmiss;                    // cas miss count
};
typedef struct tsk tsk_t;

tsk_t *tsklist;                         // task list
systls tsk_t *tskcur;                   // current task block

// show progress
#define PGR(_pgr) \
    do { \
        fputs(_pgr,stdout); \
        fflush(stdout); \
    } while (0)

// NOTE: some x86 arches need fence instructions
//   0 -- no fence instructions
//   1 -- use mfence
//   2 -- use lfence/sfence
#if _USE_BARRIER_ == 0
#define BARRIER_RELEASE             ""
#define BARRIER_ACQUIRE             ""
#define BARRIER_ALL                 ""
#elif _USE_BARRIER_ == 1
#define BARRIER_ACQUIRE             "\tmfence\n"
#define BARRIER_RELEASE             "\tmfence\n"
#define BARRIER_ALL                 "\tmfence\n"
#elif _USE_BARRIER_ == 2
#define BARRIER_ACQUIRE             "\tlfence\n"
#define BARRIER_RELEASE             "\tsfence\n"
#define BARRIER_ALL                 "\tmfence\n"
#else
#error caslock: unknown barrier type
#endif

// barrier_acquire -- acquire barrier
inline_always void
barrier_acquire(void)
{

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        BARRIER_ACQUIRE
        :
        :
        :   "memory");
}

// barrier_release -- release barrier
inline_always void
barrier_release(void)
{

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        BARRIER_RELEASE
        :
        :
        :   "memory");
}

// barrier -- barrier
inline_always void
barrier(void)
{

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        BARRIER_ALL
        :
        :
        :   "memory");
}

// casu32 -- compare and exchange four bytes
// RETURNS: 1=ok, 0=fail
inline_cas int
casu32(xptr32_p xptr,u32 oldval,u32 newval)
{
    char ok;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "   lock\n"
        "   cmpxchg     %[newval],%[xptr]\n"
        "   sete        %[ok]\n"
        :   [ok] "=r" (ok),
            [xptr] "=m" (*xptr)
        :   "a" (oldval),
            [newval] "r" (newval)
        :   "memory");

    return ok;
}

// casu64 -- compare and exchange eight bytes
// RETURNS: 1=ok, 0=fail
inline_cas int
casu64(xptr64_p xptr,u64 oldval,u64 newval)
{
    char ok;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "   lock\n"
        "   cmpxchg     %[newval],%[xptr]\n"
        "   sete        %[ok]\n"
        :   [ok] "=r" (ok),
            [xptr] "=m" (*xptr)
        :   "a" (oldval),
            [newval] "r" (newval)
        :   "memory");

    return ok;
}

// loadu32 -- load value with barrier
// RETURNS: loaded value
inline_always u32
loadu32(const xptr32_p xptr)
{
    u32 val;

    barrier_acquire();

    val = *xptr;

    return val;
}

// loadu64 -- load value with barrier
// RETURNS: loaded value
inline_always u64
loadu64(const xptr64_p xptr)
{
    u64 val;

    barrier_acquire();

    val = *xptr;

    return val;
}

// storeu32 -- store value with barrier
inline_always void
storeu32(xptr32_p xptr,u32 val)
{

    *xptr = val;

    barrier_release();
}

// storeu64 -- store value with barrier
inline_always void
storeu64(xptr64_p xptr,u64 val)
{

    *xptr = val;

    barrier_release();
}

// qsleep -- do a quick sleep
inline_always void
qsleep(int bigflg)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    if (bigflg) {
        ts.tv_sec = 1;
        ts.tv_nsec = 0;
    }
    else {
        ts.tv_sec = 0;
        ts.tv_nsec = 1000;
    }

    nanosleep(&ts,NULL);
}

// incby_tidgate -- increment by using thread id gate
void
incby_tidgate(tid_t tid)
// tid -- unique id for accessing entity (e.g. thread id)
{
    tid_t *gptr;
    tid_t oval;

    gptr = &tidgate;

    // acquire the gate
    while (1) {
        oval = 0;

        // test mode -- just do a nop instead of CAS to prove diagnostic
#if _USE_CASOFF_
        *gptr = oval;
        break;
#else
        if (tidcas(gptr,oval,tid))
            break;
#endif

        ++tskcur->tsk_casmiss;
    }

#if _USE_INCBARRIER_
    barrier_acquire();
#endif

    // increment the values
    xval += 1;
    yval += 1;

#if _USE_INCBARRIER_
    barrier_release();
#endif

    // release the gate
    // NOTE: CAS will always provide a barrier
#if _USE_CASPOST_ && (_USE_CASOFF_ == 0)
    oval = tidcas(gptr,tid,0);
#else
    tidstore(gptr,0);
#endif
}

// tskcld -- child task
void *
tskcld(void *arg)
{
    tid_t tid;
    tid_t oval;
    u64 loopcur;

    tskcur = arg;
    tid = tskcur->tsk_tid;

    // tell master thread that we're fully ready
    while (1) {
        oval = tidload(&readycnt);
        if (tidcas(&readycnt,oval,oval + 1))
            break;
    }

    // wait until we're given the starting gun
    while (1) {
        if (loadu64(&kickoff))
            break;
        qsleep(0);
    }

    // do the increments
    for (loopcur = loopmax;  loopcur > 0;  --loopcur)
        incby_tidgate(tid);

    barrier();

    // tell master thread that we're fully complete
    while (1) {
        oval = tidload(&donecnt);
        if (tidcas(&donecnt,oval,oval + 1))
            break;
    }

    return (void *) 0;
}

// tskstart -- start a child task
void
tskstart(tid_t tid)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thr;
    int err;
    tsk_t *tsk;

    tsk = tsklist + tid;
    tsk->tsk_tid = tid;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,1);
    err = pthread_create(&thr,&attr,tskcld,tsk);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    if (err)
        printf("tskstart: error -- err=%d\n",err);
}

// tskall -- run a single test
void
tskall(void)
{
    tid_t tidcur;
    tsk_t *tsk;
    u64 incmax;
    u64 val;
    int err;

    xval = 0;
    yval = 0;

    kickoff = 0;
    readycnt = 0;
    donecnt = 0;
    tidgate = 0;

    // prealloc the task blocks
    tsklist = calloc(tidmax + 1,sizeof(tsk_t));

    // start all tasks
    PGR(" St");
    for (tidcur = 1;  tidcur <= tidmax;  ++tidcur)
        tskstart(tidcur);

    // wait for all tasks to be fully ready
    PGR(" Sw");
    while (1) {
        if (tidload(&readycnt) == tidmax)
            break;
        qsleep(1);
    }

    // the starting gun -- all tasks are waiting for this
    PGR(" Ko");
    storeu64(&kickoff,1);

    // wait for all tasks to be fully done
    PGR(" Wd");
    while (1) {
        if (tidload(&donecnt) == tidmax)
            break;
        qsleep(1);
    }

    PGR(" Done\n");

    // check the final count
    incmax = loopmax * tidmax;

    // show per-task statistics
    for (tidcur = 1;  tidcur <= tidmax;  ++tidcur) {
        tsk = tsklist + tidcur;
        printf("tskall: tsk=%llu tsk_casmiss=%d (%.3f%%)\n",
            (u64) tidcur,tsk->tsk_casmiss,(double) tsk->tsk_casmiss / loopmax);
    }

    err = 0;

    // check for failure
    val = loadu64(&xval);
    if (val != incmax) {
        printf("tskall: xval fault -- xval=%lld incmax=%lld\n",val,incmax);
        err = 1;
    }

    // check for failure
    val = loadu64(&yval);
    if (val != incmax) {
        printf("tskall: yval fault -- yval=%lld incmax=%lld\n",val,incmax);
        err = 1;
    }

    if (! err)
        printf("tskall: SUCCESS\n");

    free(tsklist);
}

// main -- master control
int
main(void)
{

    loopmax = LOOPMAX;
    tidmax = TIDMAX;

    inctype = 0;
    tskall();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the Makefile.  Sorry for the extra boilerplate:

```
# caslock/Makefile -- make file for caslock
#
# options:
#   LOOPMAX -- maximum loops / thread
#
#   TIDMAX -- maximum number of threads
#
#   BARRIER -- generate fence/barrier instructions
#     0 -- none
#     1 -- use mfence everywhere
#     2 -- use lfence for acquire, sfence for release
#
#   CASOFF -- disable CAS to prove diagnostic works
#     0 -- normal mode
#     1 -- inhibit CAS during X/Y increment
#
#   CASINLINE -- inline the CAS functions
#     0 -- do _not_ inline
#     1 -- inline them (WARNING: this fails for gcc but works for clang!)
#
#   CASPOST -- increment gate release mode
#     0 -- use fenced store
#     1 -- use CAS store (NOTE: not really required)
#
#   INCBARRIER -- use extra barriers around increments
#     0 -- rely on CAS for barrier
#     1 -- add extra safety barriers immediately before increment of X/Y
#
#   TID64 -- use 64 bit thread "id"s
#     0 -- use 32 bit
#     1 -- use 64 bit
#
#   VPTR -- use volatile pointers in function definitions
#     0 -- use ordinary pointers
#     1 -- use volatile pointers (NOTE: not really required)

ifndef _CASLOCK_MK_
_CASLOCK_MK_ = 1

  OLIST += caslock.o

  ifndef LOOPMAX
    LOOPMAX = 1000000
  endif

  ifndef TIDMAX
    TIDMAX = 20
  endif

  ifndef BARRIER
    BARRIER = 0
  endif

  ifndef CASINLINE
    CASINLINE = 0
  endif

  ifndef CASOFF
    CASOFF = 0
  endif

  ifndef CASPOST
    CASPOST = 0
  endif

  ifndef INCBARRIER
    INCBARRIER = 0
  endif

  ifndef TID64
    TID64 = 0
  endif

  ifndef VPTR
    VPTR = 0
  endif

  CFLAGS += -DLOOPMAX=$(LOOPMAX)
  CFLAGS += -DTIDMAX=$(TIDMAX)

  CFLAGS += -D_USE_BARRIER_=$(BARRIER)
  CFLAGS += -D_USE_CASINLINE_=$(CASINLINE)
  CFLAGS += -D_USE_CASOFF_=$(CASOFF)
  CFLAGS += -D_USE_CASPOST_=$(CASPOST)
  CFLAGS += -D_USE_INCBARRIER_=$(INCBARRIER)
  CFLAGS += -D_USE_TID64_=$(TID64)
  CFLAGS += -D_USE_VPTR_=$(VPTR)

  STDLIB += -lpthread

  ALL += caslock
  CLEAN += caslock

  OVRPUB := 1

  ifndef OVRTOP
    OVRTOP := $(shell pwd)
    OVRTOP := $(dir $(OVRTOP))
  endif
endif

# ovrlib/rules.mk -- rules control
#
# options:
#   GDB -- enable debug symbols
#     0 -- normal
#     1 -- use -O0 and define _USE_GDB_=1
#
#   CLANG -- use clang instead of gcc
#     0 -- use gcc
#     1 -- use clang
#
#   BNC -- enable benchmarks
#     0 -- normal mode
#     1 -- enable benchmarks for function enter/exit pairs

ifdef OVRPUB
  ifndef SDIR
    SDIR := $(shell pwd)
    STAIL := $(notdir $(SDIR))
  endif

  ifndef GENTOP
    GENTOP := $(dir $(SDIR))
  endif

  ifndef GENDIR
    GENDIR := $(GENTOP)/$(STAIL)
  endif

  ifndef ODIR
    ODIR := $(GENDIR)
  endif

  PROTOLST := true
  PROTOGEN := @true
endif

ifndef SDIR
  $(error rules: SDIR not defined)
endif
ifndef ODIR
  $(error rules: ODIR not defined)
endif
ifndef GENDIR
  $(error rules: GENDIR not defined)
endif
ifndef GENTOP
  $(error rules: GENTOP not defined)
endif

ifndef _RULES_MK_
_RULES_MK_ = 1

  CLEAN += *.proto
  CLEAN += *.a
  CLEAN += *.o
  CLEAN += *.i
  CLEAN += *.dis
  CLEAN += *.TMP

  QPROTO := $(shell $(PROTOLST) -i -l -O$(GENTOP) $(SDIR)/*.c $(CPROTO))
  HDEP += $(QPROTO)

###VPATH += $(GENDIR)
###VPATH += $(SDIR)

  ifdef INCLUDE_MK
    -include $(INCLUDE_MK)
  endif

  ifdef GSYM
    CFLAGS += -gdwarf-2
  endif

  ifdef GDB
    CFLAGS += -gdwarf-2
    DFLAGS += -D_USE_GDB_
  else
    CFLAGS += -O2
  endif

  ifndef ZPRT
    DFLAGS += -D_USE_ZPRT_=0
  endif

  ifdef BNC
    DFLAGS += -D_USE_BNC_=1
  endif

  ifdef CLANG
    CC := clang
  endif

  DFLAGS += -I$(GENTOP)
  DFLAGS += -I$(OVRTOP)

  CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror
  CFLAGS += -Wno-unknown-pragmas
  CFLAGS += -Wempty-body
  CFLAGS += -fno-diagnostics-color

  # NOTE: we now need this to prevent inlining (enabled at -O2)
  ifndef CLANG
    CFLAGS += -fno-inline-small-functions
  endif

  # NOTE: we now need this to prevent inlining (enabled at -O3)
  CFLAGS += -fno-inline-functions

  CFLAGS += $(DFLAGS)
endif

all: $(PREP) proto $(ALL)

%.o: %.c $(HDEP)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $*.o $<

%.i: %.c
    cpp $(DFLAGS) -P $*.c > $*.i

%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $*.s $<

# build a library (type (2) build)
$(LIBNAME):: $(OLIST)
    ar rv $@ $(OLIST)

.PHONY: proto
proto::
    $(PROTOGEN) -i -v -O$(GENTOP) $(SDIR)/*.c $(CPROTO)

.PHONY: clean
clean::
    rm -f $(CLEAN)

.PHONY: help
help::
    egrep '^#' Makefile

caslock:: $(OLIST) $(LIBLIST) $(STDLIB)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o caslock $(OLIST) $(LIBLIST) $(STDLIB)
```

---

**NOTE:** I may have blown some of the asm constraints because when doing the CAS function as an inline, compiling with `gcc` produces incorrect results.  However, `clang` works fine with inline.  So, the default is that the CAS function is *not* inline.  For consistency, I didn't use a different default for gcc/clang, even though I could.

Here's the disassembly of the relevant function with inline as built by `gcc` (this fails):

```
00000000004009c0 <incby_tidgate>:
  4009c0:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4009c2:       f0 0f b1 3d 3a 1a 20    lock cmpxchg %edi,0x201a3a(%rip)        # 602404 <tidgate>
  4009c9:       00
  4009ca:       0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
  4009cd:       84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
  4009cf:       75 23                   jne    4009f4 <L01>
  4009d1:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
  4009d8:L00    64 48 8b 14 25 f8 ff    mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffff8,%rdx
  4009df:       ff ff
  4009e1:       83 42 04 01             addl   $0x1,0x4(%rdx)
  4009e5:       f0 0f b1 3d 17 1a 20    lock cmpxchg %edi,0x201a17(%rip)        # 602404 <tidgate>
  4009ec:       00
  4009ed:       0f 94 c2                sete   %dl
  4009f0:       84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
  4009f2:       74 e4                   je     4009d8 <L00>
  4009f4:L01    48 83 05 dc 17 20 00    addq   $0x1,0x2017dc(%rip)        # 6021d8 <ary+0xf8>
  4009fb:       01
  4009fc:       48 83 05 94 19 20 00    addq   $0x1,0x201994(%rip)        # 602398 <ary+0x2b8>
  400a03:       01
  400a04:       c7 05 f6 19 20 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x2019f6(%rip)        # 602404 <tidgate>
  400a0b:       00 00 00
  400a0e:       c3                      retq
```

Here's the disassembly of the relevant function with inline as built by `clang` (this succeeds):

```
0000000000400990 <incby_tidgate>:
  400990:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400992:       f0 0f b1 3d 3a 1a 20    lock cmpxchg %edi,0x201a3a(%rip)        # 6023d4 <tidgate>
  400999:       00
  40099a:       0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  40099d:       eb 1a                   jmp    4009b9 <L01>
  40099f:       90                      nop
  4009a0:L00    64 48 8b 04 25 f8 ff    mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffff8,%rax
  4009a7:       ff ff
  4009a9:       ff 40 04                incl   0x4(%rax)
  4009ac:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4009ae:       f0 0f b1 3d 1e 1a 20    lock cmpxchg %edi,0x201a1e(%rip)        # 6023d4 <tidgate>
  4009b5:       00
  4009b6:       0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  4009b9:L01    84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  4009bb:       74 e3                   je     4009a0 <L00>
  4009bd:       48 ff 05 e4 17 20 00    incq   0x2017e4(%rip)        # 6021a8 <ary+0xf8>
  4009c4:       48 ff 05 9d 19 20 00    incq   0x20199d(%rip)        # 602368 <ary+0x2b8>
  4009cb:       c7 05 ff 19 20 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x2019ff(%rip)        # 6023d4 <tidgate>
  4009d2:       00 00 00
  4009d5:       c3                      retq
  4009d6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4009dd:       00 00 00
```

Comment: How is this algorithm any different from just using a mutex?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It may be no different.  Even after the video, nothing precludes it.  The description is vague enough.  The gate thing meets the letter of the "law"--CAS on a 3rd integer.  I've also got a second algorithm, that is different [not a gate], with slightly different assumptions and method is definitely different.  I'll be posting that as an update to the program (e.g. can select which one).  There may be a 3rd, that I'm also working on.  The 2nd passes the diagnostic, and the 3rd needs more thought.  It's late here, so I'll post #2 in the morning.